sequence of HHH before THH
Question: You keep flipping a coin until you get either HHH or THH. What is the probability that you get a HHH sequence before THH?
What is wrong with my reasoning here:
You have an equal probability of getting T or H on the first flip. After that for both sequences, you just need to get HH so they have equal probability. That means the probability of getting HHH before THH is $\frac{1}{2}$.

the only way of getting HHH before THH is to get H on the first 3 flips; if you feel uncertain, think about three case when the 1st 3 flips give HHT

$HHH$ wins only if the start is $HHH$ , as soon as $T$ appears , $THH$ will win.

This is discussed in Pennies game (hope the spelling is correct). The paradox is that for every sequence there is a countersequence beating it in the sense that the chance it comes first is higher.

See Penney's Game

Thank you lulu , so I actually did not correctly remember it ...
